# can 32bit ubuntu system run RGBDSLAM？

Tags: slam, rgbd-slam

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I want to run RGBDSLAM, on the site of introduction 64bit ubuntu 11.10.But my machine can only install 32bit of ubuntu 11.10, Can not tried it?[link text](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/44580/can-32bit-ubuntu-system--run-rgbdslam%EF%BC%9F/) by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on ROS Answers with karma: 78 on 2012-09-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Felix Endres](https://answers.ros.org/users/113/felix-endres/) on 2012-11-15**:
So, does it work now?

**Comment by [longzhixi123](https://answers.ros.org/users/3030/longzhixi123/) on 2012-11-18**:
thanks Felix Endres, i have make the rgbdslam package ok  with http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam ,and pc is 64 bit , not 32 bit .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Although [that page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/rgbdslam#Preconditions) *appears* to say you can only run on a 64-bit Oneiric system, I suspect it really only means that the developers used that system for testing. It *should* work on other versions and platforms.

Why don't you try it on your 32-bit machine and see?

If it does not work, please edit your question, explaining what you tried and what happened.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-09-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2